# The HTTP error code 502 returned frequently when calling Google EmbeddedAssistant API by Protocol Buffers over HTTP

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to call Google Assistant API using `Protocol Buffers` (protobuf) over `HTTP`. refer to:
https://googleapis.github.io/HowToRPC#grpc-fallback-experimental

My problem is that I frequently get `HTTP` error code `502` when sending request to the back-end service.

To test the problem, I wrote a python script to send (through `HTTP POST`) the pre-built `protobuf` binaries and check the response. The test results are:

```
32KB audio data (about 1 second length of audio), 20 times post, 0 times 502 error received / 32KB 20/0, failure rate: 0%

2*32KB, 20/0, failure rate: 0%

3*32KB, 20/3, failure rate: 15%

4*32KB, 20/10, failure rate: 50%

6*32KB, 20/19, failure rate: 95%


HTTP status code is 200 for successful requests, while 502 for failed cases.
```

where we can see, the larger audio length the greater failure rate.

The `python` code to `post` pre-built `protobuf` binaries is as below. while the content of file f1 is the just `protobuf` binaries.

```
def postData():

url = "https://embeddedassistant.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2.EmbeddedAssistant/Assist"
header = {"Content-type".encode('utf-8'): "application/x-protobuf".encode('utf-8'),"Accept".encode('utf-8'):"text/plain".encode('utf-8'), "Connection".encode('utf-8'):"keep-alive".encode('utf-8'), "Authorization".encode('utf-8'):repToken.encode('utf-8')}

with open(fl) as f:
    r = requests.post(url, data=f, headers=header)
with open(fl + "_out", 'wb') as fd:
    print(r.status_code)
    fd.write(r.content)
    f.close()
    fd.close()
```

I also tried to post binary files which contain invalid `protobuf`, e.g a mp3 file,
and in this case, no matter the size of the file, the `HTTP status code` returned is always `400` with following message, **which is just expected**.

> Invalid PROTO payload received. Invalid request data in stream body, unexpected message type: 7a

It seems the back-end service sets some kind of limitation for the latency of data transfer which makes it doesn’t work well with low bandwidth connections?

Comment: I'm thinking it should be a bug of the Google's back-end service?

Hope someone here can suggest me about how to proceed.

Comment: Why are you using protobufs over HTTP? Are you not able to use gRPC?

Comment: it's almost impossible to port gRPC due to platform limitation